# Locating records not in selection using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I have a list of addresses that I need to contact. Some are listed in the attribute table, and some aren't. I'm trying to find the ones that aren't.

The list:

```
contacted = ['123 STOWE ST', '123 ROSE DR', '124 ROSE DR', '125 ROSE DR', etc.]
```

The attribute table has a `Property_Street` field that lists addresses. I want to figure out which addresses are in the contacted list **and are not** in the `Property_Street` field.

The only thing I've figured out so far is to isolate the records that have been confirmed as contacted based on the '`Contacted`' field in the attribute table. But it returns a layer, not a field, and I don't know how to isolate the `Property_Street` field from that layer.

```
query = "\"CONTACTED\" = 1"
contacted_in_tbl = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("hot_zone", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

Comment: To get a list off all addresses to subtract your list of contacted addresses from I would use list comprehension with s search cursor.

Comment: Join tables. Records with no match is your answer.

Comment: You can also use a `WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field FROM table)` subselect construct (if the data source supports it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use python then use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference

```
contacted = ['123 STOWE ST', '123 ROSE DR', '124 ROSE DR', '125 ROSE DR']
attr = ['123 STOWE ST', '123 ROSE DR', '124 ROSE DR']

print(list(set(contacted)-set(attr)))
#Same as
print(list(set(contacted).difference(attr)))

['125 ROSE DR']
['125 ROSE DR']
```

List all adresses using da.SearchCursor and list comprehension:

```
import arcpy
in_attribute_table = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'PROPERTY_STREET')]
diff = list(set(contacted)-set(in_attribute_table))
```